# What Is Wrong With My Log File In Network Render?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, network

I have sent out a rendering job using Network Render, but everytime I try to view the log file I get an error message which states "This Page Can't Be Displayed" and my Master instance remains in a "Receiving log file" state. How can I get my network to properly send its log files back to the master?

I'm running on Windows 8.1 with a local network.

Thank You In Advance.